# Open Ended Requirements Gathering

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm working on designing an operating system and would like to find out what the target users would like from the system.

My question is this: where can I ask an open ended question to gather requirements for my operating system?

The target audience is IT developers, penetration testers, hobbyists and any others who would benefit from having complete control of their system in a simple interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> where can I ask an open ended question

Not on Stack Exchange.

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”

Yours fall into the "every answer is equally valid" and a mix of the two last in the way "I'm doing X, what should I add so it becomes awesome". Instead ask how to implement the features you would like, or why should a feature be included.

Comment: Awesome answer, even though it makes my life harder. Thank you. (I would vote up your answer if I had the reputation)